# Memory leaks checked in valgrind

Tags: memory, valgrind, memory-leaks

My teacher said I have memory leaks in my program, so I used valgrind to check it. I got the following errors:

```
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4B4C: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E253: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dc040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E63D43: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E23D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4B54: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E253: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dc048 is 3 bytes after a block of size 5 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E63D43: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E23D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4931: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E266: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dc040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E63D43: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E23D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24060==    at 0x4EB493F: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5DF87: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24060==    at 0x4E5DF8D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24060==    at 0x4E5DFAF: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4E5E033: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4E5E041: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24060==    at 0x4E5E047: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E42: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E06C: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4214: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E06C: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4218: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E06C: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E1E: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CECD: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dc158 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E129: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4931: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4585: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CEE4: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dc158 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E129: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E23: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5DEFA: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dc158 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5E129: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D328: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CE85: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB4931: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5C9D2: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D0B2: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dd568 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CEE4: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E1E: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CA0F: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D0B2: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dd518 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CEE4: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E23: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CA0F: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D0B2: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dd568 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CEE4: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E1E: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CA83: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D0B2: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dd568 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CEE4: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060== 
==24060== Invalid read of size 8
==24060==    at 0x4EB2E1E: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CA9D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5D0B2: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==  Address 0x51dd568 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==24060==    at 0x4C2AD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==24060==    by 0x4EB4591: strdup (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x4E5CEE4: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==    by 0x401751: ??? (in /usr/bin/test)
==24060==    by 0x4E52804: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.16.so)
==24060==
```

Can anyone help me understand what does this errors mean?

Comment: I find out that in fact there are no memory leaks, however I would like to get rid of these other errors.

Comment: I compiled with -g flag, but it didn't help. Perhaps the problem is that I have a header file in the project?

Comment: If you haven't already, try compiling the program with -Wall to highlight all warnings, and -Werror so that warnings are treated as errors. If any issues are raised, fix them, no matter how trivial they are. I'd recommend this practice whenever you are coding in C.

Answer (score 1):

Why the valgrind output doesn't show line numbers? I don't know where to look for this errors.
I compiled my program with flag -g and used valgrind with following syntax:
valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes -q test

Comment: Did you create a new account just so you could answer your own question?

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry. :)